Prove that there exists a point $e \in [0,3]$ with $f'(e) = 1/4$, given that $f(0) =1, f(1) = f(3) = 2$ for $f : [0,3] → \mathbb{R}$ differentiable.
I tried to prove this with Rolle's Theorem and with the Mean Value Theorem for Derivatives, yet no matter how I manipulated certain functions, I never arrived at that result. Any hint or help will be greatly appreciated. As a mention, the reader is assumed to prove this with elementary continuity or differentiation theorems, no integration results are allowed.

A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

By Lagrange MVT, there exist $\xi_1\in(0,1),\xi_2\in(1,3)$ such that
$$1=f(1)-f(0)=f'(\xi_1),\quad 0=f(3)-f(1)=2f'(\xi_2).$$
Then by Darboux theorem, there exists $e\in(\xi_1,\xi_2)\subset(0,3)$,such that
$f'(e)=1/4$.

If we use the Mean Value Theorem, there exists $e_{1} \in (1,3)$ s.t.
$$ \frac{f(3)-f(1)}{3-1} = f'(e_{1}) \iff f'(e_{1})=0$$
Similarly there is $e_{2} \in (0,1)$ such that:
$$ \frac{f(1)-f(0)}{1-0} = 1 = f'(e_{2})$$
But any derivative satisfies the Intermidiate Value Property, therefore as $1/4 \in (f'(e_2) ; f'(e_1)) $, there exists $e \in (e_2,e_1)$ such that $ f'(e)=1/4$.
So we are done!
Though the other answer is a more standard way of doing this.

Here is a quick proof:
Define $G(x)=f(x)-\frac{1}{4}x, $ we have $G(0)=1,G(1)=\frac{7}{4}$ and $G(3)=\frac{5}{4}$. If there does not exist such $e$, then $G'(x)$ is either positive or negative. But this is not the case since $G(1)-G(0)=G'(\xi_1)>0$ and $G(1)-G(3)=G'(\xi_2)<0$.

Hint: consider $g(x) = f(x) - x/4$. Note that $g(0) = 1$, $g(1) = 7/4$, $g(3) = 5/4$.
Reasons you may figure this: the conclusion of Rolle's will be that there exists $e \in [0, 3]$ such that $g'(e) = 0$. We know $f$ in itself isn't going to work, so we think about $g(x) = f(x) - h(x)$. So the conclusion will be $f'(e) = h'(e)$. But we won't get any information about the point $e$ from Rolle's apart from the interval its contained in, the best we might hope for is a bound on $h'(e)$ (but this won't depend too specifically on $e$). So we may suspect that $h'(x) = 1/4$ identically and indeed this works.
